# PrintStream doesn't print correctly unicode characters ( UTF-16)

Tags: java, unicode, printing, utf-16

I want to print correctly unicode (let's say greek characters ) but I have problems. For example :

```
PrintStream oStream = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");
oStream.write(" Customer    : Γειά σου\r\n".getBytes());
oStream.write(" ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ     : 00000234242\r\n".getBytes());
oStream.flush();
oStream.close();

                             OR
 OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "UTF-16");
    oStream.write(" Customer    : Γειά σου\r\n");
oStream.write(" ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ     : 00000234242\r\n");
oStream.flush();
oStream.close();
```

The question is if there is any solution to print correctly all of the caharacters. I think for Greek characters UTF-16 is ok.

Comment: What does this print out?

Comment: Aren't Greek characters UTF-16?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 can be used to encode all characters  in Unicode.

Comment: Γειά σου = "Ο¨Ο¨Ο¨Ο¨Ο something like that as if they are garbages

Comment: "I have problems" is far too vague a description. What exactly are you seeing? What is `client`?

Comment: client is an output stream & more aspecific a socket to output the result to a printer. The "problems" are the garbages characters.

Comment: This works fine on Eclipse. Is it maybe the receiving end that isn't printing them correctly?

Comment: How are you reading these bytes on the receiving end of the socket?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos the printer part is interesting! What make/model is it? How do you interface it? Is it 100% that it can accept UTF-8?

Comment: Are you sure that your IDE saves the source files UTF encoded?

Comment: Printer model is : Xerox WC 24 PCL

Comment: @Sotirios: it's for a Java developer perhaps easier to understand that "Unicode" at its whole own is basically an `interface` and that "UTF-8", "UTF-16", etc are concrete implementations of it. I.e. they support all the same functionality (the same characters), but do it under the covers somewhat differently (a different byte sequence to represent the individual characters).

Comment: @StathisAndronikos Another question: how many "garbage" characters are printed? Isn't it by any chance **2x** the number of Greek characters in the text? I mean are there 2 garbage characters in the output for 1 Greek character on the input?

Comment: When I print UTF-8 are  exactly x2 but with this model EPSON XP-600

Answer (score 3):

This is quite possibly the issue:

```
oStream.write(" Customer    : Γειά σου\r\n".getBytes());
oStream.write(" ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ     : 00000234242\r\n".getBytes());
```

You're calling `String.getBytes()` with no encoding, to get a byte array using the *platform default encoding*. That's almost always a bad idea anyway, *and* it means that the fact that you specified UTF-8 earlier is irrelevant to these two lines. By the time the `PrintStream` gets the data, it's already in binary.

Try this instead:

```
oStream.print(" Customer    : Γειά σου\r\n");
oStream.print(" ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ     : 00000234242\r\n");
```

Notes:

- I would advise against using either `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter`. They swallow exceptions.
- If you're only writing text, you should use a `Writer` subclass rather than an `OutputStream` subclass
- It's unclear whether your source code is even being handled correctly: you need to check that whatever you're using to compile your code knows what encoding your source file is using.

I suggest you wrap your output stream in an `OutputStreamWriter`... that will allow you to specify the encoding, you won't have to worry about accidentally writing binary data (as the API doesn't allow it) and you won't see exceptions getting swallowed.

Comment: oStream.write() doesn't accept string and forces you to add ".getBytes()". Try it for yourself!

Comment: @StathisAndronikos but it has a [`print(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) method, so I think this is a typo

Comment: Produces the same result. I have the same problem too.

Comment: Hmmm, I must argue with myself: the print method is documented as `Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes **according to the platform's default character encoding**, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.`

Comment: @ppeterka66: The documentation is wrong - at least according to the implementation I'm looking at. Bear in mind that if the documentation were correct, the encoding specified in the constructor would be pointless.

Comment: @StathisAndronikos: No, it shouldn't produce the same result... unless your platform default encoding is already UTF-8. But you haven't given us a clear enough description of how you're diagnosing the problem, which makes that rather hard. I hadn't checked whether or not there's a `write` method - sorry about that. Have edited it to `print` instead. But using `OutputStreamWriter` would be better anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet And I didn't believe the "When Jon Skeet says so, and the documentation says different, the documentation is wrong" joke... But reading up on that it seems likely, that the constructor accepting the encoding was added later, and that handles the encoding - so the documentation should read `according to the platform's default character encoding - **or the one specified in the constructor**`

Comment: oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "UTF-16"); Produces the same garbages.

Comment: @ppeterka66: Yes, that's my belief too, according to the implementation.

Comment: @StathisAndronikos: Are you looking for UTF-16 or UTF-8? You need to be very clear. You've also *still* not told us what "the same garbage" is, or how you're diagnosing this. Basically we can't help you any further without more information. Perhaps the problem is on the receiving side? Or with your source code, as noted in the third bullet point in my answer.

Comment: I think for greek characters UTF-16 is ok!

Answer (score 0):

**Never rely on the default encoding**, much better to always specify, if you want to stick with the redundant way of creating a byte array to print, instead of the much more elegant, intuitive, and in every way superior way of using the String directly...

```
oStream.write(" Customer    : Γειά σου\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
oStream.write(" ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ     : 00000234242\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

From comment of OP

> client is an output stream & more aspecific a socket to output the **result to a printer**

That might be an issue! I wouldn't trust printers to get the UTF-8 plain string correctly. Be sure to test it with plain, ASCII strings to make sure everything else is OK.

**EDIT**

#### Xerox WorkCentre 24 PCL specific issues

From the [PDL Reference Guide for the Xerox WorkCentre/WorkCentre Pro Series](http://www.office.xerox.com/support/dctips/dc05cc0359.pdf%E2%80%8E):

> This document is not intended as a PS or PCL reference manual, but a guide for using the extended features WorkCentre’s in PS, PCL **or ASCII** print jobs.

There is not a single mention of UTF-8 anywhere...

From this [doc at SAP: Xerox_SAP_Device_Types](http://ftp.xerox.com/support/sap-device-types-for-xerox-printers/file-redirect/enus.html?operatingSystem=winxp&contentId=120529)

> To enable the Xerox® printer for Unicode printing, obtain the Unicode Printing Solution for models which support the UTF-8 character set, where an optional kit is available called Xerox® International Unicode Printing.

This doesn't sound good...

Comment: Same problem but I will try with UTF-16

Comment: @StathisAntonikos I dont think that will make a difference! I strongly suspect that the printer can not accept UTF-8.

Comment: @StathisAndronikos Does it work with very dumb test string? Like plain ASCII "ABCD" - does it print correctly?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos Is it 100% sure that the printer is compatible with UTF-8 input? Is there a documentation for it?

Comment: Xerox WC 24 PCL I think supports UTF-8

Comment: @StathisAndronikos I tried some googling, and updated the answer, it is not too clear if it can do UTF-8 in plain mode...